# 1C 8.3 Мобильная платформа не загружает приложение с apache 2.2

Tags: android, apache, 1с, apache2, мобильная-разработка

Пытаюсь опубликовать мобильное приложение 1С для работы на андроид. На компьютере установлен Apache 2.2, Брендмауэр отключен, PC находится в одной локальной сети со смартфоном и со смартфона по IP PC отображается страница сервера apache.

[image: Публикация приложения из базы 1С]

Тем не менее из мобильной платформы загрузить приложение не получается: 
[image: Загрузка приложения]

Подробное описание этой ошибки содержит следующий текст:

Файл не обнаружен 'http://192.168.1.11/WorkMA'
по причине:
Ошибка работы с Интернет: ресурс не найден (404). 
по причине:
Ошибка работы с Интернет: ресурс не найден (404)

Comment: Попробуй из обычного браузера с компа; Деталей уже не помню, но там может не подключаться из-за ограничений по доступу (ограничения Апача, ограничения ОС) ...

Answer (score 0):

Запусти `1С` от имени администратора и ещё раз опубликуй.

***P. S.:***
Я не пробовал и не утверждаю, но разве тебе не внешний `IP` указывать то надо? Этот то локальный.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло общее название имени и каталога. К примеру:
Имя: curaSauri
...
Каталог: C:\curaSauri
Не знаю че за приколы, но у меня сработало